# Jitsi for Flutter with limited feature flag

Tags: flutter, jitsi-meet

I had integrated Jitsi Meet SDK with my flutter application but how can I set a specific person as a moderator, and moreover unmute option is available to everyone how can I enable it to the moderator and disable that feature for everyone.

I had tried this approach to make someone as a moderator and unmute all, lobby mode disable and screen sharing disable is not available as a feature flag in JITsi.

```
if (admin == "admin") {
    featureFlag.kickOutEnabled = true;
    featureFlag.meetingPasswordEnabled = true;
    featureFlag.videoShareButtonEnabled = true;
    featureFlag.liveStreamingEnabled = true;
    featureFlag.meetingPasswordEnabled=true;
    featureFlag.toolboxAlwaysVisible=false;
```

**Package of Interest**

https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet

```
jitsi_meet: ^4.0.0
```

Comment: Some featureflags are not supporting flutter. Did you find something userful realated this?

Comment: i later used `https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet_wrapper` and `https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet_wrapper_platform_interface` and its working perfectly well for me

Comment: This is was helpful. Can you please tell me that where can I find my screen recordings i-e where it is stored?

Comment: hmmmm, buddy, recording is stored on jitis server but if you want to have it stored on your server you have to host jitis on your server

Comment: There is no option of changing role from moderator to participants? And kick out is not working?

Comment: you have to define that yourself using IF statement or SWITCH statement, take for example you already have users registered in your app, and from your registration you can assign role to the users. (2) in connecting to the jitsi package you then use IF OR SWITCH statement to determine what role you are to give to the user in the video call. by the way kick-out work's perfectly for me

Comment: what platform are you building for?
ios? android? or both?

Comment: Both android and iOS. I am using flutter

Comment: you will need to check for ios requirement using the above package I made mention of

Comment: I have used the role of a user, but if i set FeatureFlag.isKickOutEnabled to false, it still can kick out other users

Comment: can you please explain your logic so i can know how to explain to you. but I guess you are applying it to user instead of admin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245269/discussion-between-muhammad-ullah-and-zionnite).